# MS Access 2019 - How to fix "Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected" [PDF Export]

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf-generation

I had a project that worked until recently and now I cannot export MS Access Report to PDF either manually via the Navigation Pane or Ribbon.

The only change that I can highlight is that our IT department upgraded us from MS Office 2016 to MS Office 2019.

I also cannot export the report via VBA.

When trying to export the report to PDF. I am receiving the following error message. Cannot figure our how to reset this

> Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected.
>
> - The file may be open. If so, close it, and then save the output data to the file again.
> - If you are using a template, check to make sure the template exists.
> - If the file isn't open, check to make sure that you have enough free disk space.
> - Make sure that the file exists on the path specified.
> - Check to make sure you have permission to write to the specified folder.

[image: MS Access Error Message Microsoft Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected popup.]

**Steps to recreate:**

1. Right Click on a report in the Navigation Pane > select export > PDF or XPS. Select a file location, give it a name and select PDF as a file type.
2. Open a report in Print Preview > Select PDF of XPS from the Data Section of the Print Preview Ribbon, give it a name and select PDF as a file type.
3. Open a report in Print Preview > Select EMAIL from the Data Section of the Print Preview Ribbon, Select PDF Format (*.pdf) from the Send Object As popup
4. VBA Code

```
Docmd.OpenReport "MyReportName", acViewPreview,,,acHidden   
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MyReportName", acFormatPDF, "c:\users\<myuser>\desktop\MyReportTrialRun_MMDDYYYY.pdf", , , , acExportQualityPrint
Docmd.Close acReport, "MyReportName"
```

(When running as part of the VBA process -- it just does not create the file no message)

**System Configuration:**

- MS Access - Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019, Version 1808
- Build 10386.20017 Click-to-Run. Windows 10 Education Version 20H2
- Installed on ‎12/‎21/‎2021
- OS build 19042.1415
- Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
- Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz  3.30 GHz Installed RAM 16.0 GB
- System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Internal Hard Drive has approx. 80GB of free space remaining

**Troubleshooting Steps I Have Already Taken**

0. VBA Code Compiles without errors
1. Compact and Repair Access Database File - No Change In Issue
2. Tried to save with different file names - No Change In Issue
3. Tried to save in different locations (other folders on desktop, other folders on local drive, on shared network drives and on external USB drives) - No Change In Issue
4. Create A New Report using a subset of the data - No Change In Issue
5. Ran Office Repair (Quick Repair) - No Change In Issue
6. Ran Office Repair (Online Repair) - No Change In Issue
7. Opened report in print preview, printed the report using the printer "Microsoft Print to PDF" -- got PDF
8. Opened report and tried to export XPS file - received XPS file
9. Opened report and tried to export to HTML - received HTML files
10. Opened report and tried to export to Excel - received XLSX file

I am at a loss as to how to fix this issue.

Besides resolving this issue -- is there a way to via VBA "Print" to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" 'Printer' and specify where the file is saved? I need to do this automated since I send multiple reports via email and/or shared folders that I do not want to have to do the steps manually each run.

For disclosure > I previously posted on UtterAccess (https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/2063349/posts/2799785) looking for assistance with this issue.

Comment: All computers running Access 2019 have issue? Try on a computer using Access 2016. Verify issue is with Access 2019. As for the other question about MS Print to PDF - I think not.

Comment: Will have to wait until Monday or Tuesday when I get back to my office and other team members that can test will be available

Comment: @June7 - I just tried it on another computer and it was able to export.

The funny thing is that I can export other reports to PDF in other Access Databases.

Comment: To the same folder?

Comment: @June7 Yes. To move it from one computer to another I put it on a Thumb Drive and ran it from there on both computers.

Comment: You are able to export reports in other Access db to same folder as the one that fails?

Comment: @June7 yes. Yep and strangely Enough even a few other reports from the same db.

Comment: Since the report is not opened with any filter criteria, try OutputTo without first opening and then the Close action would also not be needed. Not optimistic that will be successful as it is essentially same as outputting from Navigation Pane, but only thing I can offer. Really can't explain issue so have no idea how to resolve.

Comment: @June7 I will try anything at this point.

Comment: @June7 I even did a complete uninstall of office 2019 rebooted and installed office 365 and it is the same issue

Comment: Since the issue doesn't occur with other computers, last resort suggestion is to replace computer or re-image.

Comment: I have been asking for a replacement unit for 3 years as my current computer is 7 years old. Hoping it gets approved in the next budget.

Comment: Am having the same issue. Just like @psycoperl I am strangely able to create a PDF and export it, if for example, I output it to an email as an attachment. But a straight output as PDF will not be saved to the folder. I should note that I am also on Access 2019 and did not have this issue with Access 2013, from which I upgraded.